# Issue while creating file on local drive through Formatter in Java

Tags: java

I am unable to create a file on my local hard drive using Formatter class in java while it is working fine if i create it in workspace.

Following is the code i am using to create file into my local drive but its not working :

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Formatter x ;

        try{
        x = new Formatter("C:\\raw.txt");
        System.out.println("You have created a new file");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You have got an error while creating file");
        }
    }
}
```

But if we change the path in the arguments then its working fine. The following code is working fine :

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Formatter x ;

        try{
        x = new Formatter("raw.txt");
        System.out.println("You have created a new file");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You have got an error while creating file");
        }
    }
}
```

But through this code the file is getting created only in workspace in the project. How to create it in local drive.

The error I get is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\raw.txt (Access is denied) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.Formatter.(Unknown Source)

Comment: Modify your catch block to include `e.printStackTrace();` after your error message so you can see what the actual problem is.  I suspect you don't have rights to create a new file in the C:\ root directory.

Comment: Thanks Jim , on adding the e.printStackTrace() , i have got the actual error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\raw.txt (Access is denied)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hence i have change the Drive to D:\ and its working fine .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with permissions, run command prompt or IDE with administrator rights or another option is you can change destination drive from C:\ to D:\ or which ever is applicable in your case.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh , you are right on changing the destination path from C:\ to D:\ , i am able to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Trying both options (absolute and relative path-string) are working fine in my system...
Further more, the error message is indicating

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\raw.txt (Access is denied) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.Formatter.(Unknown Source)

wich means your App or in this case Eclipse has no granted permissions to write files in C

Try modifying the access permit on C

Comment: Thanks , yes modifying the access is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Give the path of the file as drive other than Operating system drive because Windows does not allow to create a file by external application without adding certain permissions.

So I would suggest you to go for D,E or any drive other than OS drive